# Why setState of react-select's menu selection making modal close state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a modal which listens to the outside click of modal and triggers onclose method which closes the modal. Now I added react select to the modal, and after choosing one of the options it's making my modal go on close state.
I am capturing the outside click from one of the medium articles.

```
function useOuterClickNotifier(onOuterClick, innerRef) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (innerRef.current) {
      document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    }
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);

    function handleClick(e) {
      if (innerRef.current && !innerRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        onOuterClick(e);
      }
    }
  }, [onOuterClick, innerRef]);
}
```

https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-with-react-hook-ba77c37c7e82

My `index.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";
import Modal from "../Modal";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  function onCloseModal() {
    console.log("Why closing?");
    setOpen(false);
  }

  function openModal() {
    setOpen(true);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {isOpen && (
        <Modal closeModal={onCloseModal}>
          <div className="card">
            <Select options={options} />
          </div>
        </Modal>
      )}
      <button onClick={openModal}>Open modal</button>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

How do I fix it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/usegooglemap-repro-x3q37?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

System info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.5
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.4.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 78.0.3904.97
    Firefox: 69.0
    Safari: 12.1.1
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
    react-dom: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
    react-scripts: 3.2.0 => 3.2.0
```

Comment: i think the issue is the event is propagating to Modal closeModal function. So we need to stopPropagation from the Select component

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS That should not be the problem because the target of the event is being checked to be outside of the modal. For some reason the check returns false.

Comment: @trixn i have posted an answer can you verify it, because i think the event is bubbling up so it calls the closeModal function. let me know if anything wrong in the answer so i can update or will remove it

Comment: I updated my answer with an improved solution that allows it to listen the `click` event. The solution better tackles the original problem so i'd go with that. `mousedown` would be possible too but it behaves slightly different and also wouldn't protect you from a third party component listening to `mousedown` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that this is caused by the fact that the select menu has already been unmounted when the event listener of your hook is called. React does not know about click handlers attached manually so it will start updating the DOM immediately. By the time the event is handled by your listener the DOM node that was click has already been removed.

To prevent that you can pass `true` as a third parameter to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. This parameter is `useCapture`. If `true` it will call your listener during the capturing phase **before** any listeners of the target elements.

[From mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> **`useCapture`** *[Optional]*
>
> A Boolean indicating whether events of this type will be dispatched to
>   the registered `listener` before being dispatched to any `EventTarget`
>   beneath it in the DOM tree. Events that are bubbling upward through
>   the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture. Event
>   bubbling and capturing are two ways of propagating events which occur
>   in an element that is nested within another element, when both
>   elements have registered a handle for that event. The event
>   propagation mode determines the order in which elements receive the
>   event. See DOM Level 3 Events and JavaScript Event order for a
>   detailed explanation. If not specified, `useCapture` defaults to `false`.

[image: Edit useGoogleMap repro]

```
function useOuterClickNotifier(onOuterClick, innerRef) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (innerRef.current) {
      document.addEventListener("click", handleClick, true);
    }
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick, true);

    function handleClick(e) {
      if (innerRef.current && !innerRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        onOuterClick(e);
      }
    }
  }, [onOuterClick, innerRef]);
}
```